# Tibco Spotfire Build Error in Package builder

Tags: visual-studio, spotfire

When I try to build Visual Studio project using SpotFire package builder. I am getting the following error

> Project has unresolved assembly references.
>
> Spotfire.Dxp.Worker.ServiceContracts version 14.10.7525.5058 is
> referenced by SpotFire.Dxp.Web.Dll. Tibco.Ems, version 1.0.700.12 is
> referenced by SpotFire.Dxp.Web.Dll.

Answer (score 0):

1)Launch visual studio command line prompt, and add the assembly file to the global assembly cache (GAC) using the following command: gacutil /i [assembly file path]\assemblyname.dll

For example,
C:\PackageBuilder\Binaries> gacutil /i Spotfire.Dxp.Web.dll

2)Validate and Save the custom extension project.
Note: If you would like to remove the assembly from the GAC, run: gacutil /u assemblyName -  gacutil /u Spotfire.Dxp.Web